# why my map livedata is not called even though I have change the value?

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, mutablelivedata

I am new in MVVM and Android Architecture component. so I have repository like this

```
object RestaurantRepository {

    val restaurants : LiveData<ArrayList<Restaurant>> = RestaurantClient.restaurants

    private var count : LiveData<Int> = Transformations.map(restaurants) {

        Log.d("debugLog","map")

        it.size
    }

    fun searchRestaurants(query: String, latitude:Double, longitude: Double) {

        mQuery = query

        RestaurantClient.searchRestaurants(
            query = query,
            latitude = latitude,
            longitude = longitude,
            start = 0
        )
    }

}
```

and I have client that getting data using Retrofit

```
object RestaurantClient {

    val restaurants = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Restaurant>>()


    private val restaurantService = RetrofitServiceGenerator.getInstance(RestaurantAPI::class.java)

    fun searchRestaurants(query: String, latitude:Double, longitude: Double, start: Int) {

        val call = restaurantService.searchRestaurants(
            radius = 2000,
            query = query,
            latitude = latitude,
            longitude = longitude,
            start = start,
            count = NUMBER_OF_DOCUMENT_PER_PAGE
        )



        call.enqueue(object: Callback<RestaurantListBaseResponse> {

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<RestaurantListBaseResponse>, t: Throwable) {

                // if there is an error while sending data to server or while parsing the data

            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<RestaurantListBaseResponse>, response: Response<RestaurantListBaseResponse>) {

                if (response.isSuccessful) {

                    val listOfRestaurants = response.body()!!.restaurants
                    val restos = ArrayList<Restaurant>()

                    for (i in listOfRestaurants ) {
                        restos.add(i.restaurant)
                    }

                    restaurants.postValue(restos)


            }

        })


    }
```

I believe, I get the data from server and post it through `restaurants` MutableLiveData in my `RestaurantClient`. so I assume because there is a change in Livedata, then it will trigger the Transformations.map , but that log in `count` never appear in my Logcat.

this count is private for only in `RestaurantRepository` , this is just for a test because I am still learning about livedata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Transformations)

`The transformations aren't calculated unless an observer is observing the returned LiveData object.` So, you need to subscribe to `count` LiveData to make Transformations work.